# Why is the received buffer size bigger than originally sent via socket?

Tags: c++, winapi, networking

I have the following:

```
struct sockaddr_in* server = (struct sockaddr_in*)sockAddr;

ULONG addr = htonl(server->sin_addr.s_addr);
USHORT port = server->sin_port;

char* frame[sizeof(USHORT) + sizeof(ULONG)];

memcpy(frame, &port, sizeof(USHORT));
memcpy(&frame[2], &addr, sizeof(ULONG));


int result = send(s, (const char*)frame, sizeof(frame), 0);
```

The size of `USHORT` is 2 bytes and `ULONG` 4, why when receiving the total result of bytes is 24 instead?

Comment: Assuming `char*` is 4 bytes, and you have an array of 6 of them, it'll be 24. Looks like you meant `char frame[...]`

Comment: @JamesRoot Makes sense now, thank you! :)

Comment: Just curious, why are you transmitting a `sockaddr_in` to the peer? And why translate the byte order of `server->sin_addr.s_addr` but not of `server->sin_port` as well?  The peer already has access to the `sockaddr_in` of the sender via `getpeername()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hey! Because sin_port is already translated. And the reason is because that's the destination of server the client has to connect to afterwards, it's basically proxifier. Original -> Localhost -> Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`frame` is an array of char pointer, and I assume that char pointers on your system is 4 bytes. That's why `sizeof(frame)` is 24 bytes. You probably want an array of chars instead.

```
// array of char, not char *
char frame[sizeof(USHORT) + sizeof(ULONG)];
```

Comment: Well I feel stupid now. Thank you!